# React - TypeScript - Multi-dimensional Object - Need Support

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I have an object like below. I need to remove the particular section of array object only.

I need to remove this based on some condition. Please provide some suggestions on this.

Can we use single line array de-structuring option or any other solutions?

The only unique identifier here is *"menuKey": "sidebarRewards"*

**Part that needs to be removed:**

```
{
  "menuKey": "sidebarRewards",
  "label": "Smart Rewards",
  "iconSetName": "narrow",
  "description": "",
  "url": "example.com/account/sidebar/index.tmpl#rewards"
}
```

**Original Object:**

```
{
  "profile-welcome": {
    "type": "user-profile-welcome",
    "params": {
      "welcomeBack": "Welcome Back!"
    }
  },
  "sidebar-tier": {
    "type": "user-sidebar-tier",
    "params": {
      "rewardsLink": {
        "label": "REWARDS",
        "url": "/smartrewards"
      }
    }
  },
  "account-links": {
    "type": "account-links",
    "params": {
      "menu": [
        {
          "menuKey": "sidebarAccount",
          "label": "My Account",
          "iconSetName": "narrow",
          "description": "",
          "url": "example.com/account/index.tmpl"
        },
        {
          "menuKey": "sidebarSettings",
          "label": "Account Settings",
          "iconSetName": "narrow",
          "description": "",
          "url": "example.com/account/profile_preferences.tmpl"
        },
        {
          "menuKey": "sidebarRewards",
          "label": "Smart Rewards",
          "iconSetName": "narrow",
          "description": "",
          "url": "example.com/account/sidebar/index.tmpl#rewards"
        },
        {
          "menuKey": "sidebarSignOut",
          "label": "Sign Out ",
          "iconSetName": "narrow",
          "description": "",
          "url": "example.com/account/signin.tmpl?_SUBMIT=signout"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "showcase": {
    "type": "showcase",
    "params": {
      "brandServices": {
        "header": "SKIN SERVICES",
        "infoLink": {
          "label": "",
          "url": ""
        },
        "list": [
          {
            "showCaseKey": "firstBrandShowcase",
            "title": "Skin Services.",
            "teaser": "Our team of Consultants is at your fingertips for tips and advice.",
            "label": "See All Skin Services",
            "url": "/services"
          },
          {
            "showCaseKey": "secondBrandShowcase",
            "title": "Try on makeup.",
            "teaser": "Find your perfect shades and use your phone to try them on.",
            "label": "Select Makeup to Try On",
            "url": "/clinicalreality"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the array `filter` method. For example:

```
if (condition) {
    account-links.menu = account-links.menu.filter(menu => {
        return menu.menuKey !== "sidebarAccount"
    }
}
```

This will override the `account-links.menu` with a filtered version based off of whatever criteria you choose to check for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Let me check and get back here.